# Filling rest of Array

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I am writing a two's complement program where I convert decimal to binary using an array. I also want to have 8 Bits binary.

Since, for example, 22 is 10110 in binary, I want to fill the rest of the array with zeros, but I wasn't able to find a way how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
static void  toBin(int number){
    int[] bin = new int[8];
    int i =0;
    while (number > 0){
        bin[i] = number % 2;
        number = number/2;
        i++;
    }

    // Here is where I would like to add zeros if the size of the array is below 0

    for (int j = i-1; j>=0;j--){
        System.out.println(bin[j]); //Array gets reserved
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
int number =22;
int bits[]= new int[8];
for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
    if(number>0){
        bits[7-i]=number%2;
        number/=2;
    }
    else{
        bits[7-i]=0;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
    System.out.print(bits[i]);
}
```

I think, I have resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called *"Arrays"* that has a method called *"fill()"*.

The syntax is *"Arrays.fill()"*.

Inside the round brackets, after *"fill"*, you have to put the value that will fill the rest of the array.

The example below fills the elements which have index from 0 to 5 (without 6) with the value 1.

```
int[] intArray = new int[8];

Arrays.fill(ints2, 0, 6, 1) ;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Here is the output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is initialized with zeros when it is created. You need just to change the required digits with 1 and rest will remain zeros. Try to start filling the array from 8th digit then decrement your counter so you may reach the most left digit.

Comment: Adding code with an answer is always helpful, please add it.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize the whole string and reserve some space, like eight characters.

```
String binaryStr = "00000000";
for (int i = 0; i < binaryStr.Length (); i++)
{
    if (binaryShouldBeOne)
    {
        binaryStr[i] = '1';
    } else 
    {
        binaryStr[i] = '0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
    int out[] = new int[8];
    int in = 22;

    int i = out.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && in > 0) {
        out[i] = in % 2;
        in /= 2;
        i--;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < out.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(out[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
```